# why python string has both index and find

Tags: python, indexing, find

I know the only difference between `find` and `index` methods is that, `find` returns -1 when it does not find the substring while `index` raises an exception.
Why we need both `index` and `find`? while `find` works as well as `index`.

Comment: You've just stated the key difference between them.  What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a specific situation that `find` works better than `index`?

Comment: If you don't want to raise an exception, then find is infinitely better in that situation..

Comment: `index()` is also available with lists and tuples (other sequences), whereas `find()` is specific to strings.

Comment: If there is a situation that we want to prevent raising an exception, why Python programmers have not added `find` to list and tuple?

Comment: @cdarke `index()` works a little differently between strings and other sequences though. A string can be thought of a list of characters while `index()` will also search for multiple characters and not only one. It is not possible to search for a sublist using `index()`, for example.

Comment: The main reason is that `string.find()` was added _after_ `.index()` to make it easier to write such code, without having to set up a `try/except` block. The previous method has also been kept for backwards compatibility.